# Uncomplete installation of the RASA package with the issue: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'HISTORY.rst'

Tags: python, pip, rasa

i have been using rasa for the past few weeks without problems. But recently i had issues with the installation of Spacy, leading me to uninstall an reinstall python. The issue may have occurred because of some dualities between python3.8 and 3.9 which i wasnt abled to pinpoint.

After deleting all python version from my computer, i just reinstalled python 3.9.2. and reinstall rasa with:

```
pip3 install rasa
```

this gave me the next output:

```
Collecting rasa
  Using cached rasa-1.10.2-py3-none-any.whl (510 kB)
Collecting sklearn-crfsuite<0.4,>=0.3
  Using cached sklearn_crfsuite-0.3.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (12 kB)
Collecting tensorflow-estimator==2.1.0
  Using cached tensorflow_estimator-2.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (448 kB)
Collecting ruamel.yaml<0.17,>=0.16
  Using cached ruamel.yaml-0.16.13-py2.py3-none-any.whl (111 kB)
Collecting pydot<1.5,>=1.4
  Using cached pydot-1.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (21 kB)
Collecting psycopg2-binary<2.9.0,>=2.8.2
  Using cached psycopg2_binary-2.8.6-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (1.2 MB)
Collecting jsonpickle<1.5,>=1.3
  Using cached jsonpickle-1.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (36 kB)
Collecting pymongo[srv,tls]<3.9.0,>=3.8.0
  Downloading pymongo-3.8.0.tar.gz (649 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 649 kB 3.3 MB/s
Collecting SQLAlchemy<1.4.0,>=1.3.3
  Using cached SQLAlchemy-1.3.23-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (1.2 MB)
Collecting coloredlogs<11.0,>=10.0
  Using cached coloredlogs-10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (47 kB)
Collecting python-dateutil<2.9,>=2.8
  Using cached python_dateutil-2.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (227 kB)
Collecting sanic<20.0.0,>=19.12.2
  Using cached sanic-19.12.5-py3-none-any.whl (73 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=41.0.0 in c:\users\louip\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from rasa) (49.2.1)
Collecting pytz<2020.0,>=2019.1
  Using cached pytz-2019.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (509 kB)
Collecting slackclient<3.0.0,>=2.0.0
  Using cached slackclient-2.9.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (96 kB)
Collecting terminaltables<3.2.0,>=3.1.0
  Using cached terminaltables-3.1.0.tar.gz (12 kB)
Collecting colorclass<2.3,>=2.2
  Using cached colorclass-2.2.0.tar.gz (17 kB)
Collecting twilio<6.27,>=6.26
  Using cached twilio-6.26.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (979 kB)
Collecting pykwalify<1.8.0,>=1.7.0
  Using cached pykwalify-1.7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (40 kB)
Collecting python-socketio<4.6,>=4.4
  Using cached python_socketio-4.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (51 kB)
Collecting webexteamssdk<1.4.0,>=1.1.1
  Using cached webexteamssdk-1.3.tar.gz (56 kB)
Collecting PyJWT<1.8,>=1.7
  Using cached PyJWT-1.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
Collecting tqdm<4.46,>=4.31
  Using cached tqdm-4.45.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (60 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy<2.0,>=1.16 in c:\users\louip\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from rasa) (1.20.0)
Collecting tensorflow_hub<0.9,>=0.7
  Using cached tensorflow_hub-0.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (101 kB)
Collecting tensorflow-probability<0.10,>=0.7
  Using cached tensorflow_probability-0.9.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.2 MB)
Collecting matplotlib<3.3,>=3.1
  Using cached matplotlib-3.2.2-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (8.9 MB)
Collecting rasa-sdk<2.0.0,>=1.10.0
  Using cached rasa_sdk-1.10.3-py3-none-any.whl (39 kB)
Collecting gevent<1.6,>=1.4
  Using cached gevent-1.5.0.tar.gz (5.3 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Collecting sanic-cors<0.11.0,>=0.10.0b1
  Using cached Sanic_Cors-0.10.0.post3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (17 kB)
Collecting absl-py<0.10,>=0.9
  Using cached absl-py-0.9.0.tar.gz (104 kB)
Collecting colorhash<1.1.0,>=1.0.2
  Using cached colorhash-1.0.3-py3-none-any.whl (4.0 kB)
Collecting multidict<5.0,>=4.6
  Using cached multidict-4.7.6.tar.gz (50 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Collecting prompt-toolkit<3.0,>=2.0
  Using cached prompt_toolkit-2.0.10-py3-none-any.whl (340 kB)
Collecting oauth2client==4.1.3
  Using cached oauth2client-4.1.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (98 kB)
Collecting async_generator<1.11,>=1.10
  Using cached async_generator-1.10-py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
Collecting python-engineio<3.13,>=3.11
  Downloading python_engineio-3.12.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (49 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 49 kB 3.2 MB/s
Collecting questionary<1.6.0,>=1.5.1
  Using cached questionary-1.5.2-py3-none-any.whl (26 kB)
Collecting ujson<3.0,>=1.35
  Downloading ujson-2.0.3.tar.gz (7.1 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 7.1 MB 3.3 MB/s
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Collecting rasa
  Using cached rasa-1.10.1-py3-none-any.whl (509 kB)
Collecting packaging<19.1,>=19.0
  Using cached packaging-19.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (26 kB)
Collecting rasa
  Using cached rasa-1.10.0-py3-none-any.whl (509 kB)
  Using cached rasa-1.9.7-py3-none-any.whl (497 kB)
Collecting cloudpickle<1.3.0,>=1.2.0
  Using cached cloudpickle-1.2.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (25 kB)
Collecting jsonpickle<1.4,>=1.3
  Using cached jsonpickle-1.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (32 kB)
Collecting tensorflow_hub<0.8,>=0.7
  Using cached tensorflow_hub-0.7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (89 kB)
Collecting rasa
  Using cached rasa-1.9.6-py3-none-any.whl (497 kB)
  Using cached rasa-1.9.5-py3-none-any.whl (496 kB)
  Using cached rasa-1.9.4-py3-none-any.whl (495 kB)
  Using cached rasa-1.9.3-py3-none-any.whl (495 kB)
  Using cached rasa-1.9.2-py3-none-any.whl (495 kB)
  Using cached rasa-1.9.1-py3-none-any.whl (495 kB)
  Using cached rasa-1.9.0-py3-none-any.whl (495 kB)
  Using cached rasa-1.8.3-py3-none-any.whl (483 kB)
Collecting tqdm<4.32.0,>=4.31.0
  Using cached tqdm-4.31.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (48 kB)
Collecting python-socketio<4.5,>=4.4
  Using cached python_socketio-4.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (50 kB)
Collecting python-engineio<3.12,>=3.11
  Using cached python_engineio-3.11.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (49 kB)
Collecting rocketchat_API<0.7.0,>=0.6.31
  Using cached rocketchat_API-0.6.36-py3-none-any.whl (9.5 kB)
Collecting rasa
  Using cached rasa-1.8.2-py3-none-any.whl (483 kB)
  Using cached rasa-1.8.1-py3-none-any.whl (481 kB)
  Using cached rasa-1.8.0-py3-none-any.whl (481 kB)
  Using cached rasa-1.7.4-py3-none-any.whl (575 kB)
  Using cached rasa-1.7.3-py3-none-any.whl (575 kB)
  Using cached rasa-1.7.2-py3-none-any.whl (575 kB)
  Using cached rasa-1.7.1-py3-none-any.whl (574 kB)
  Using cached rasa-1.7.0-py3-none-any.whl (573 kB)
  Using cached rasa-1.6.2-py3-none-any.whl (559 kB)
  Using cached rasa-1.6.1-py3-none-any.whl (559 kB)
Collecting tensorflow-probability~=0.7.0
  Using cached tensorflow_probability-0.7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (981 kB)
Collecting webexteamssdk~=1.1
  Using cached webexteamssdk-1.6-py3-none-any.whl (113 kB)
Collecting tensor2tensor~=1.14.0
  Using cached tensor2tensor-1.14.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.6 MB)
Collecting sanic-jwt~=1.3
  Using cached sanic-jwt-1.6.0.tar.gz (19 kB)
Collecting sanic-cors==0.9.9.post1
  Using cached Sanic_Cors-0.9.9.post1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
Collecting redis~=3.3.5
  Using cached redis-3.3.11-py2.py3-none-any.whl (66 kB)
Collecting absl-py>=0.8.0
  Using cached absl_py-0.12.0-py3-none-any.whl (129 kB)
Collecting attrs>=18
  Using cached attrs-20.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (49 kB)
Collecting twilio~=6.0
  Using cached twilio-6.54.0.tar.gz (471 kB)
Collecting rasa-sdk~=1.6.0
  Using cached rasa_sdk-1.6.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (32 kB)
Collecting sanic~=19.9.0
  Using cached sanic-19.9.0-py3-none-any.whl (73 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.20 in c:\users\louip\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from rasa) (2.25.1)
Collecting rasa
  Using cached rasa-1.6.0-py3-none-any.whl (558 kB)
  Using cached rasa-1.5.3-py3-none-any.whl (530 kB)
  Using cached rasa-1.5.2-py3-none-any.whl (529 kB)
  Using cached rasa-1.5.1-py3-none-any.whl (529 kB)
  Using cached rasa-1.5.0-py3-none-any.whl (527 kB)
  Using cached rasa-1.4.6-py3-none-any.whl (518 kB)
  Using cached rasa-1.4.5-py3-none-any.whl (517 kB)
  Using cached rasa-1.4.4-py3-none-any.whl (517 kB)
  Using cached rasa-1.4.3-py3-none-any.whl (518 kB)
Collecting networkx~=2.3.0
  Using cached networkx-2.3.zip (1.7 MB)
Collecting kafka-python~=1.4
  Using cached kafka_python-1.4.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (266 kB)
Collecting pika~=1.0.0
  Using cached pika-1.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (148 kB)
Collecting matplotlib~=3.0
  Using cached matplotlib-3.3.4-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (8.5 MB)
Collecting pymongo[srv,tls]~=3.8
  Using cached pymongo-3.11.3-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (383 kB)
Collecting scikit-learn~=0.20.2
  Using cached scikit-learn-0.20.4.tar.gz (11.7 MB)
Collecting python-telegram-bot~=11.0
  Using cached python_telegram_bot-11.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (326 kB)
Collecting rasa
  Using cached rasa-1.4.2-py3-none-any.whl (516 kB)
  Using cached rasa-1.4.1-py3-none-any.whl (516 kB)
  Using cached rasa-1.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (515 kB)
  Using cached rasa-1.3.10-py3-none-any.whl (507 kB)
Collecting rasa-sdk~=1.3.0
  Using cached rasa_sdk-1.3.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (32 kB)
Collecting rasa
  Using cached rasa-1.3.9-py3-none-any.whl (506 kB)
  Using cached rasa-1.3.8-py3-none-any.whl (505 kB)
  Using cached rasa-1.3.7-py3-none-any.whl (505 kB)
  Using cached rasa-1.3.6-py3-none-any.whl (505 kB)
  Using cached rasa-1.3.4-py3-none-any.whl (504 kB)
  Using cached rasa-1.3.3-py3-none-any.whl (503 kB)
  Using cached rasa-1.3.2-py3-none-any.whl (502 kB)
  Using cached rasa-1.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (502 kB)
  Using cached rasa-1.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (502 kB)
  Using cached rasa-1.2.12-py3-none-any.whl (471 kB)
  Using cached rasa-1.2.11-py3-none-any.whl (471 kB)
  Using cached rasa-1.2.10-py3-none-any.whl (471 kB)
  Using cached rasa-1.2.9-py3-none-any.whl (471 kB)
  Using cached rasa-1.2.8-py3-none-any.whl (471 kB)
  Using cached rasa-1.2.7-py3-none-any.whl (471 kB)
  Using cached rasa-1.2.6-py3-none-any.whl (470 kB)
  Using cached rasa-1.2.5-py3-none-any.whl (470 kB)
  Using cached rasa-1.2.4-py3-none-any.whl (469 kB)
  Using cached rasa-1.2.3-py3-none-any.whl (469 kB)
  Using cached rasa-1.2.2-py3-none-any.whl (468 kB)
  Using cached rasa-1.2.1-py3-none-any.whl (468 kB)
  Using cached rasa-1.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (468 kB)
  Using cached rasa-1.1.8-py3-none-any.whl (464 kB)
  Using cached rasa-1.1.7-py3-none-any.whl (455 kB)
  Using cached rasa-1.1.6-py3-none-any.whl (453 kB)
  Using cached rasa-1.1.5-py3-none-any.whl (452 kB)
  Using cached rasa-1.1.4-py3-none-any.whl (447 kB)
  Using cached rasa-1.1.3-py3-none-any.whl (446 kB)
  Using cached rasa-1.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (444 kB)
  Using cached rasa-1.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (444 kB)
  Using cached rasa-1.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (444 kB)
  Using cached rasa-1.0.9-py3-none-any.whl (440 kB)
  Using cached rasa-1.0.8-py3-none-any.whl (440 kB)
  Using cached rasa-1.0.7-py3-none-any.whl (439 kB)
  Using cached rasa-1.0.6-py3-none-any.whl (438 kB)
  Using cached rasa-1.0.5-py3-none-any.whl (438 kB)
  Using cached rasa-1.0.4-py3-none-any.whl (438 kB)
  Using cached rasa-1.0.3-py3-none-any.whl (438 kB)
  Using cached rasa-1.0.2-py3-none-any.whl (438 kB)
  Using cached rasa-1.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (436 kB)
  Using cached rasa-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (436 kB)
  Using cached rasa-0.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (6.1 kB)
Collecting rasa-nlu
  Using cached rasa_nlu-0.15.1-py3-none-any.whl (147 kB)
Collecting rasa-core
  Using cached rasa_core-0.14.5-py3-none-any.whl (212 kB)
Collecting pytz~=2018.9
  Using cached pytz-2018.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl (510 kB)
Collecting rasa-core
  Using cached rasa_core-0.14.4-py3-none-any.whl (212 kB)
  Using cached rasa_core-0.14.3-py3-none-any.whl (212 kB)
  Using cached rasa_core-0.14.2-py3-none-any.whl (212 kB)
  Using cached rasa_core-0.14.1-py3-none-any.whl (212 kB)
  Using cached rasa_core-0.14.0-py3-none-any.whl (212 kB)
  Using cached rasa_core-0.13.8-py3-none-any.whl (205 kB)
Collecting keras-applications==1.0.6
  Using cached Keras_Applications-1.0.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (44 kB)
Collecting fbmessenger~=5.0
  Using cached fbmessenger-5.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Collecting redis~=2.0
  Using cached redis-2.10.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (64 kB)
Collecting rasa-core
  Using cached rasa_core-0.13.7-py3-none-any.whl (205 kB)
  Using cached rasa_core-0.13.6-py3-none-any.whl (205 kB)
  Using cached rasa_core-0.13.5-py3-none-any.whl (204 kB)
  Using cached rasa_core-0.13.4-py3-none-any.whl (204 kB)
  Using cached rasa_core-0.13.3-py3-none-any.whl (204 kB)
  Using cached rasa_core-0.13.2-py3-none-any.whl (204 kB)
  Using cached rasa_core-0.13.1-py3-none-any.whl (204 kB)
  Using cached rasa_core-0.13.0-py3-none-any.whl (204 kB)
  Using cached rasa_core-0.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (204 kB)
Collecting prompt-toolkit==1.0.14
  Using cached prompt_toolkit-1.0.14-py3-none-any.whl (248 kB)
Collecting networkx~=2.0
  Using cached networkx-2.5-py3-none-any.whl (1.6 MB)
Collecting python-telegram-bot~=10.0
  Using cached python_telegram_bot-10.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (298 kB)
Collecting typing~=3.0
  Using cached typing-3.7.4.3.tar.gz (78 kB)
Collecting pika~=0.11.2
  Using cached pika-0.11.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (107 kB)
Collecting fakeredis~=0.10.0
  Using cached fakeredis-0.10.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (27 kB)
Collecting pykwalify<=1.6.0
  Using cached pykwalify-1.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (38 kB)
Collecting rasa-core-sdk~=0.12.1
  Using cached rasa_core_sdk-0.12.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
Collecting python-socketio~=2.0
  Using cached python_socketio-2.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (33 kB)
Collecting pyyaml~=3.12
  Using cached PyYAML-3.13.tar.gz (270 kB)
Collecting scikit-learn~=0.19.0
  Using cached scikit-learn-0.19.2.tar.gz (9.7 MB)
Collecting ConfigArgParse~=0.13.0
  Using cached ConfigArgParse-0.13.0.tar.gz (31 kB)
Collecting slackclient~=1.0
  Using cached slackclient-1.3.2.tar.gz (16 kB)
Collecting flask-cors~=3.0
  Using cached Flask_Cors-3.0.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl (14 kB)
Collecting h5py~=2.0
  Using cached h5py-2.10.0.tar.gz (301 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: six~=1.0 in c:\users\louip\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from rasa-core->rasa) (1.15.0)
Collecting rasa-core
  Using cached rasa_core-0.12.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (204 kB)
  Using cached rasa_core-0.12.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (203 kB)
Collecting keras~=2.0
  Using cached Keras-2.4.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (36 kB)
Collecting rasa-core
  Using cached rasa_core-0.12.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (203 kB)
  Using cached rasa_core-0.12.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (201 kB)
  Using cached rasa_core-0.11.12-py2.py3-none-any.whl (179 kB)
Collecting graphviz~=0.9.0
  Using cached graphviz-0.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
Collecting rasa-core
  Using cached rasa_core-0.11.11-py2.py3-none-any.whl (179 kB)
  Using cached rasa_core-0.11.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl (179 kB)
  Using cached rasa_core-0.11.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl (179 kB)
  Using cached rasa_core-0.11.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (179 kB)
  Using cached rasa_core-0.11.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (178 kB)
  Using cached rasa_core-0.11.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (178 kB)
  Using cached rasa_core-0.11.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (178 kB)
  Using cached rasa_core-0.11.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (178 kB)
  Using cached rasa_core-0.11.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (168 kB)
Collecting graphviz~=0.8.0
  Using cached graphviz-0.8.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
Collecting rasa-core
  Using cached rasa_core-0.11.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (166 kB)
  Using cached rasa_core-0.11.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (166 kB)
Collecting mattermostwrapper~=2.0
  Using cached mattermostwrapper-2.2.tar.gz (2.5 kB)
Collecting rasa-core
  Using cached rasa_core-0.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (166 kB)
  Using cached rasa_core-0.10.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
Collecting ruamel.yaml~=0.15.0
  Using cached ruamel.yaml-0.15.100.tar.gz (318 kB)
Collecting tqdm~=4.0
  Using cached tqdm-4.59.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (74 kB)
Collecting jsonpickle~=0.9.0
  Using cached jsonpickle-0.9.6.tar.gz (67 kB)
Collecting flask~=1.0
  Using cached Flask-1.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (94 kB)
Collecting future~=0.16
  Using cached future-0.18.2.tar.gz (829 kB)
Collecting rasa-nlu
  Using cached rasa_nlu-0.13.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (145 kB)
Collecting rasa-core
  Using cached rasa_core-0.10.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
  Using cached rasa_core-0.10.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
Collecting rasa-nlu
  Using cached rasa_nlu-0.12.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (131 kB)
Collecting rasa-core
  Using cached rasa_core-0.10.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (132 kB)
  Using cached rasa_core-0.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (132 kB)
  Using cached rasa_core-0.9.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (125 kB)
  Using cached rasa_core-0.9.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (125 kB)
  Using cached rasa_core-0.9.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (125 kB)
  Using cached rasa_core-0.9.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (125 kB)
  Using cached rasa_core-0.9.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (125 kB)
  Using cached rasa_core-0.9.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (121 kB)
  Using cached rasa_core-0.9.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (121 kB)
  Using cached rasa_core-0.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (121 kB)
  Using cached rasa_core-0.9.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (121 kB)
  Using cached rasa_core-0.8.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (103 kB)
Collecting h5py
  Using cached h5py-3.2.1-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (2.8 MB)
Collecting fakeredis
  Using cached fakeredis-1.4.5-py3-none-any.whl (35 kB)
Collecting fbmessenger<5.0.0
  Downloading fbmessenger-4.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Collecting apscheduler
  Using cached APScheduler-3.7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (59 kB)
Collecting redis
  Using cached redis-3.5.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (72 kB)
Collecting rasa-nlu
  Using cached rasa_nlu-0.11.5.tar.gz (55 kB)
Collecting graphviz
  Using cached graphviz-0.16-py2.py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
Collecting ConfigArgParse
  Downloading ConfigArgParse-1.4.tar.gz (45 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 45 kB 3.4 MB/s
Collecting pandoc
  Using cached pandoc-1.0.2.tar.gz (488 kB)
Collecting scikit-learn
  Using cached scikit_learn-0.24.1-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (6.9 MB)
Collecting jsonpickle
  Using cached jsonpickle-2.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (37 kB)
Collecting python-telegram-bot
  Using cached python_telegram_bot-13.4.1-py3-none-any.whl (448 kB)
Collecting rasa-core
  Using cached rasa_core-0.8.5.tar.gz (76 kB)
Collecting nbsphinx
  Using cached nbsphinx-0.8.2-py3-none-any.whl (24 kB)
Collecting rasa-core
  Using cached rasa_core-0.8.4.tar.gz (76 kB)
  Using cached rasa_core-0.8.3.tar.gz (76 kB)
  Using cached rasa_core-0.8.2.tar.gz (76 kB)
  Using cached rasa_core-0.8.1.tar.gz (75 kB)
  Using cached rasa_core-0.8.0.tar.gz (75 kB)
  Using cached rasa_core-0.7.9.tar.gz (61 kB)
  Using cached rasa_core-0.7.7.tar.gz (61 kB)
  Using cached rasa_core-0.7.6.tar.gz (60 kB)
  Using cached rasa_core-0.7.5.tar.gz (60 kB)
  Using cached rasa_core-0.7.4.tar.gz (60 kB)
  Using cached rasa_core-0.7.3.tar.gz (59 kB)
  Using cached rasa_core-0.7.2.tar.gz (59 kB)
  Using cached rasa_core-0.7.1.tar.gz (60 kB)
  Using cached rasa_core-0.7.0.tar.gz (60 kB)
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of rasa to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
Collecting rasa
  Using cached rasa-0.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (6.1 kB)
  Using cached rasa-0.0.5-py3-none-any.whl
  Using cached rasa-0.0.4.tar.gz (5.0 kB)
  Using cached rasa-0.0.3.tar.gz (4.7 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\louip\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\louip\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-pjlvx_xv\\rasa_2e5bbaea763d4f8b9abf11dcaa6b3e0c\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\louip\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-pjlvx_xv\\rasa_2e5bbaea763d4f8b9abf11dcaa6b3e0c\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\louip\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-908ibd4q'
         cwd: C:\Users\louip\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pjlvx_xv\rasa_2e5bbaea763d4f8b9abf11dcaa6b3e0c\
    Complete output (7 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\louip\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pjlvx_xv\rasa_2e5bbaea763d4f8b9abf11dcaa6b3e0c\setup.py", line 14, in <module>
        with open('HISTORY.rst', 'r', 'utf-8') as f:
      File "c:\users\louip\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\codecs.py", line 905, in open
        file = builtins.open(filename, mode, buffering)
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'HISTORY.rst'
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/77/56/5d44415d54043fb441b910bf86fa36bbb3b5565a507ba4ea933117cf109f/rasa-0.0.3.tar.gz#sha256=409e502bc20a29db848b68766decacad15a9cbeb68d1afd90add9945945c9048 (from https://pypi.org/simple/rasa/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info 
Check the logs for full command output.
  Using cached rasa-0.0.2.tar.gz (3.9 kB)
  Using cached rasa-0.0.1.tar.gz (1.6 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<3,>=2.5 in c:\users\louip\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.20->rasa) (2.10)       
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<5,>=3.0.2 in c:\users\louip\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.20->rasa) (4.0.0) 
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\louip\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.20->rasa) (2020.12.5)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\louip\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.20->rasa) (1.26.4)
Installing collected packages: rasa
Successfully installed rasa-0.0.5
```

the result is that rasa is install in version 0.0.5 when it should be in version 2.4.

i have no clue why an error occurred at the end as it did not happen the first i downloaded it a few weeks ago.

What should i do to resolve this issue?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`rasa` 2.4](https://pypi.org/project/rasa/2.4.0/) declares compatibility with Python 3.6, 3.7 and 3.8 but not 3.9 so `pip` is trying to find one compatible with 3.9 or at least one that doesn't declare any restriction. It finds such release at version 0.0.5.

To use `rasa` 2.4 downgrade to Python 3.8.

PS. Don't hurry up to upgrade to the latest Python — 3rd-party packages are usually not so fast. Currently Python 3.7 and 3.8 are the best.